# Stuck at Could not build wheels for cryptography which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python, django

Upgraded pip command still having this message. I am trying to install django-allauth.
The following error is generated while using pip install django-allauth
(venv) C:\Users\Tubai\PycharmProjects\food>pip install django-allauth
Collecting django-allauth
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/70/8c/18e9fd164b0e1e578995cf916da49a074b22a629a71c6017455d1ba151e1/django-allauth-0.44.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Django>=2.0 in c:\users\tubai\documents\pycharmprojects\ldjangocrash\venv\lib\site-packages (from django-allauth) (3.1.7)
Collecting python3-openid>=3.0.8 (from django-allauth)
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e0/a5/c6ba13860bdf5525f1ab01e01cc667578d6f1efc8a1dba355700fb04c29b/python3_openid-3.2.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests-oauthlib>=0.3.0 (from django-allauth)
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a3/12/b92740d845ab62ea4edf04d2f4164d82532b5a0b03836d4d4e71c6f3d379/requests_oauthlib-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests (from django-allauth)
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/29/c1/24814557f1d22c56d50280771a17307e6bf87b70727d975fd6b2ce6b014a/requests-2.25.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyjwt[crypto]>=1.7 (from django-allauth)
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3f/32/d5d3cab27fee7f6b22d7cd7507547ae45d52e26030fa77d1f83d0526c6e5/PyJWT-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref<4,>=3.2.10 in c:\users\tubai\documents\pycharmprojects\ldjangocrash\venv\lib\site-packages (from Django>=2.0->django-allauth) (3.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\users\tubai\documents\pycharmprojects\ldjangocrash\venv\lib\site-packages (from Django>=2.0->django-allauth) (2021.1)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in c:\users\tubai\documents\pycharmprojects\ldjangocrash\venv\lib\site-packages (from Django>=2.0->django-allauth) (0.4.1)
Collecting defusedxml (from python3-openid>=3.0.8->django-allauth)
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/07/6c/aa3f2f849e01cb6a001cd8554a88d4c77c5c1a31c95bdf1cf9301e6d9ef4/defusedxml-0.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting oauthlib>=3.0.0 (from requests-oauthlib>=0.3.0->django-allauth)
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/57/ce2e7a8fa7c0afb54a0581b14a65b56e62b5759dbc98e80627142b8a3704/oauthlib-3.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting chardet<5,>=3.0.2 (from requests->django-allauth)
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/19/c7/fa589626997dd07bd87d9269342ccb74b1720384a4d739a1872bd84fbe68/chardet-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 (from requests->django-allauth)
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0c/cd/1e2ec680ec7b09846dc6e605f5a7709dfb9d7128e51a026e7154e18a234e/urllib3-1.26.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests->django-allauth)
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/a0/5f06e1e1d463903cf0c0eebeb751791119ed7a4b3737fdc9a77f1cdfb51f/certifi-2020.12.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<3,>=2.5 (from requests->django-allauth)
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a2/38/928ddce2273eaa564f6f50de919327bf3a00f091b5baba8dfa9460f3a8a8/idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cryptography<4.0.0,>=3.3.1; extra == "crypto" (from pyjwt[crypto]>=1.7->django-allauth)
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9b/77/461087a514d2e8ece1c975d8216bc03f7048e6090c5166bc34115afdaa53/cryptography-3.4.7.tar.gz
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting cffi>=1.12 (from cryptography<4.0.0,>=3.3.1; extra == "crypto"->pyjwt[crypto]>=1.7->django-allauth)
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c6/92/9188a1dff4934d0bd18df7f92dc481324b3342814cea34849b393ea2d232/cffi-1.14.5-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting pycparser (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography<4.0.0,>=3.3.1; extra == "crypto"->pyjwt[crypto]>=1.7->django-allauth)
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ae/e7/d9c3a176ca4b02024debf82342dab36efadfc5776f9c8db077e8f6e71821/pycparser-2.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: cryptography
Building wheel for cryptography (PEP 517) ... error
Complete output from command C:\Users\Tubai\Documents\PycharmProjects\ldjangocrash\venv\Scripts\python.exe c:\users\tubai\documents\pycharmprojects\ldjangocrash\venv\lib\site-packages\pip
-19.0.3-py3.7.egg\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py build_wheel C:\Users\Tubai\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpw0h2fd70:
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography
copying src\cryptography\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography
copying src\cryptography\fernet.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography
copying src\cryptography\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography
copying src\cryptography_*about*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography
copying src\cryptography_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat
copying src\cryptography\hazmat_der.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat
copying src\cryptography\hazmat_oid.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat
copying src\cryptography\hazmat_types.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat
copying src\cryptography\hazmat_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\x509
copying src\cryptography\x509\base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\x509
copying src\cryptography\x509\certificate_transparency.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\x509
copying src\cryptography\x509\extensions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\x509
copying src\cryptography\x509\general_name.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\x509
copying src\cryptography\x509\name.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\x509
copying src\cryptography\x509\ocsp.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\x509
copying src\cryptography\x509\oid.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\x509
copying src\cryptography\x509_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\x509
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\backends
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\interfaces.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\backends
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\backends
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\bindings
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\bindings
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\cmac.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\constant_time.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\hashes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\hmac.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\keywrap.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\padding.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\poly1305.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives_asymmetric.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives_cipheralgorithm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives_serialization.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\aead.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\backend.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\ciphers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\cmac.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\decode_asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\dh.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\dsa.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\ec.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\ed25519.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\ed448.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\encode_asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\hashes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\hmac.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\ocsp.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\poly1305.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\rsa.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\x25519.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\x448.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\x509.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\binding.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl_conditional.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\dh.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\dsa.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\ec.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\ed25519.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\ed448.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\padding.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\rsa.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\x25519.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\x448.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers\aead.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers\algorithms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers\base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers\modes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf\concatkdf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf\hkdf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf\kbkdf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf\pbkdf2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf\scrypt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf\x963kdf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization\base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization\pkcs12.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization\pkcs7.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization\ssh.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor\hotp.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor\totp.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor
copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor
running egg_info
writing src\cryptography.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to src\cryptography.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to src\cryptography.egg-info\requires.txt
writing top-level names to src\cryptography.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'src\cryptography.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs_build'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'vectors'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.github'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'release.py'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'dev-requirements.txt'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'mypy.ini'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.zuul.d'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.zuul.playbooks'
adding license file 'LICENSE'
adding license file 'LICENSE.APACHE'
adding license file 'LICENSE.BSD'
adding license file 'LICENSE.PSF'
writing manifest file 'src\cryptography.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
copying src\cryptography\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cryptography
running build_ext
generating cffi module 'build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\_padding.c'
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
generating cffi module 'build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\_openssl.c'
running build_rust

```
      =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================
      If you are seeing a compilation error please try the following steps to
      successfully install cryptography:
      1) Upgrade to the latest pip and try again. This will fix errors for most
         users. See: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip
      2) Read https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation.html for specific
         instructions for your platform.
      3) Check our frequently asked questions for more information:
         https://cryptography.io/en/latest/faq.html
      4) Ensure you have a recent Rust toolchain installed:
         https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation.html#rust
      5) If you are experiencing issues with Rust for *this release only* you may
         set the environment variable `CRYPTOGRAPHY_DONT_BUILD_RUST=1`.
      =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================

  error: can't find Rust compiler

  If you are using an outdated pip version, it is possible a prebuilt wheel is available for this package but pip is not able to install from it. Installing from the wheel would avoid the n
eed for a Rust compiler.

  To update pip, run:

      pip install --upgrade pip

  and then retry package installation.

  If you did intend to build this package from source, try installing a Rust compiler from your system package manager and ensure it is on the PATH during installation. Alternatively, rustu
p (available at https://rustup.rs) is the recommended way to download and update the Rust compiler toolchain.

  This package requires Rust >=1.41.0.

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for cryptography
  Running setup.py clean for cryptography
  Complete output from command C:\Users\Tubai\Documents\PycharmProjects\ldjangocrash\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Tubai\\AppData\\Local\\T
emp\\pip-install-fq61nc2j\\cryptography\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" clean --a
ll:
  running clean
  removing 'build\temp.win-amd64-3.7' (and everything under it)
  removing 'build\lib.win-amd64-3.7' (and everything under it)
  'build\bdist.win-amd64' does not exist -- can't clean it
  'build\scripts-3.7' does not exist -- can't clean it
  removing 'build'
  running clean_rust
  error: can't find Rust compiler

  If you are using an outdated pip version, it is possible a prebuilt wheel is available for this package but pip is not able to install from it. Installing from the wheel would avoid the n
eed for a Rust compiler.

  To update pip, run:

      pip install --upgrade pip

  and then retry package installation.

  If you did intend to build this package from source, try installing a Rust compiler from your system package manager and ensure it is on the PATH during installation. Alternatively, rustu
p (available at https://rustup.rs) is the recommended way to download and update the Rust compiler toolchain.

  This package requires Rust >=1.41.0.

      =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================
      If you are seeing a compilation error please try the following steps to
      successfully install cryptography:
      1) Upgrade to the latest pip and try again. This will fix errors for most
         users. See: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip
      2) Read https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation.html for specific
         instructions for your platform.
      3) Check our frequently asked questions for more information:
         https://cryptography.io/en/latest/faq.html
      4) Ensure you have a recent Rust toolchain installed:
         https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation.html#rust
      5) If you are experiencing issues with Rust for *this release only* you may
         set the environment variable `CRYPTOGRAPHY_DONT_BUILD_RUST=1`.
      =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================


  ----------------------------------------
  Failed cleaning build dir for cryptography
Failed to build cryptography
Could not build wheels for cryptography which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Comment: error: can't find Rust compiler. Install rust compiler?

Comment: does htis problem got solved ?

Answer (score 4):

As @rossettistone says, cryptography uses Rust code since version 3.4.
Then you can go into 2 ways: Installing Rust or going to a lower version.

**Install Rust**

To install Rust on Linux or macOS, as its [installation guide](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch01-01-installation.html#installing-rustup-on-linux-or-macos) says (remember to install curl by apt-get install curl):

```
$ curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.3 https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh
```

if it doesn't works, you could try this alternative method:

```
$ curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh
```

**Install older version of cryptography**

Version 3.3.2 or lower is the one you want to install:

```
$ pip install cryptography==3.3.2
```

or, if you have already installed it, you can change the version by:

```
$ pip install --force-reinstall -v "cryptography==3.3.2"
```

I got into this solution when installing paramiko on ARM architecture with debian OS so i had to do this with cryptography and bcrypt packages. For bcrypt I installed the version 3.2.2, being the last one who don't use Rust code.

Answer (score 3):

`cryptography` recently changed its dependencies to include Rust. There are a number of longer discussions on this topic (e.g. https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/5771), but upgrading to the latest version of `pip` is likely to fix your issue.

`pip install --upgrade pip`

If that doesn't work, have you tried all of the suggestions in the "DEBUG ASSISTANCE" section of the logs you pasted into your question?

Comment: None of them worked, Atlast , I created a new virtual environment and installed the required libraries.

Answer (score 1):

For me, upgrading pip helped solve the issue on M1 Mac Monterrey.

`pip3 install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and upgrading the pip solved it.

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).